# Using Flow with a HOC, and Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, flowtype, higher-order-components, flow-typed

I am facing a problem with flow typing. Here is the code, stripped down to the relevant parts:

```
/* @flow */
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

export type InjectedProps = {||};
type StateProps = {||};
type DispatchProps = {||};
type OwnProps = {||};
type ReduxProps = {|
  ...OwnProps,
  ...StateProps,
  ...DispatchProps,
|};
type Props = {|
  ...ReduxProps,
|};
type AppState = {
}

export default function withDetailsNavigation<OP: {}>(
  WrappedComponent: React.AbstractComponent<{ ...OP, ...InjectedProps, ...Props }>
): React.AbstractComponent<$Diff<Props, InjectedProps>> {
  class DetailsNavigation extends React.PureComponent<Props> {
    render() {
       const injectedProps = {}

       // $FlowFixMe - props is incompatible with OP - how to fix?
       return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} {...injectedProps} />;
    }  
  }  
  const mapStateToProps = {}
  const mapDispatchToProps = {}


  return connect<ReduxProps, OwnProps, StateProps, DispatchProps, AppState, _>(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(DetailsNavigation);
}
```

And this is the error that I am getting:

> Cannot create `WrappedComponent` element because  props [1] is incompatible with  `OP`
>
> [2] Flow(InferError)
>
> WithDetailsNavigation.jsx(180, 20): [1] props
>
> WithDetailsNavigation.jsx(113, 46): [2] `OP`

There must be something wrong with the typing of the AbstractComponents, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

There error message here could definitely be better, and I think I know what's causing that issue (and I'll fix it!).

[Here's a smaller way to reproduce the issue](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuyYAhgM5gBKApiQMZFR5yZgDketDbA3KqtQAeuQmAIBPbNTABJAHYArag2oATAArNsFALxgA3gB9DAXz4SpYAMoESBaprjaweo6fOTpAEXRlsdugALR2dXYzNUC2kAeQQ5EN0DcI9LGlUAV0EElyTUMDAAOiLY+K0yABo8wqKbOwcyyvyigp8-AOCG1HdIzzBssKrmtMyEyu6osABBbGxa+xz9VBN+IREiVWooEnSYRnS5BnQ4OTAEdAJAr2pbdBgyADkSADd0AHM7I7kAHmj1AC4DCYAHwACiqAHU8CQZmoAMIsXByahyAgAmj0AgFSYAIzIBChDHhOGOyIIX301QKv3KlNGlPkShUGjKYGBqAAlAYqnRjniwNgygD+mAQXIdjAASQ5OJ2Xx8pwCOk8CcvpDoVJVETEaSDM0BU4yCZ8sAgXwTEA).

`OP` has an upper bound of `{}`, which is inexact. That means that you might have some properties that are not included in the type. `Props` effectively has type `{||}`, since all of the spreads are exact objects with no properties. So you're trying to pass `{||}` to something that might have required props!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am not sure if exact vs inexact is the issue. The error is still present when leaving off all exact props: https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuyYAhgM5gBKApiQMZFR5yZgDketDbA3KqtQAeuQmAIBPbNTABJAHYArag2oATAArNsFALxgA3gF8+EqWADKBEgWqa42sHqMnJ0gCLoy2a3QAWdhydjVFNpAHkEOQDdA2DQqjUAV0FoxwNUMDAAOhyIqK0yABoM7JzLa1sC4sycrI8vH38q1DjXMFSnEtqaVWTo4uCBYXwiVWooEkSYRkS5BnQ4OTAEdAJfN2ordBgyADkSADd0AHNrBbkAHjD1AC5YgD4AChKAdTwSbClVAGEWXDlqHICHcaPQCFkAIIAIzIBHeDF+OEWgIIF30pSy10KGP6GPkShUGgKYEM91QAEp0pk6ItYWBsAU7h0wI85FMYHcSHJxOS+JlOAREnglhc3h8voj-iiDLUGfYyIZMsB7nxDEA

Comment: Even without the exactness, there could be some required props in `OP` that are not captured by `Props` (which now has type `{}`). Suppose I called the function with:

```
withDetailsNavigation<{| foo: number |}>(Component);
```

In this case, `foo` would be required but spreading `OwnProps = {}` may not have `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is in wrong usage of generic. You can't declare OwnProps outside the function and declare it as a generic simultaneously.

See https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoAlgWwA5wE4AuyYAhgM5gBKApiQMZFR5yZgDketDbA3KqtQAeuQmAIBPbNTABJAHYArag2oATAArNsFALxgA3gB9DAXz4SpYAMoESBaprjaweo6fOTpAEXRlsdugALR2dXYzNUC2kAeQQ5EN0DcI9LGlUAV0EElyTUMDAAOiLY+K0yABo8wqKbOwcyyvyigp8-AOCG1HdIzzBssKrmtMyEyu6BYXwiVWooEnSYRnS5BnQ4OTAEdAJAr2pbdBgyADkSADd0AHM7NbkAHmj1AD4ACiqAdTwSbClVAGEWLg5NQ5AQAFxULgEAoAQQARmQCF8GACcOsQQQ7kZqgV5EoVBoGjjHuUwKYnqgAJQGKp0daIsDYMoQ7HNPHKeyEpwVYnqUmmHIvOQLGAQkhycSUvj5TgEdJ4DZ3T7fX6ooEYgzNJnckz5YBPPgmIA

Answer (score 0):

For HOC componenent, why don't you use `React.ComponentType` https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-componenttype